# app.exe.manifest settings are ignored after moving the executable to a different location

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw, gdi

I'm building my Windows app with MinGW:

```
windres app.rc -O coff -o app.res
gcc -w -mwindows -o app.exe app.c  app.res
```

Here's my app.exe.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.1.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="controls"
    type="win32"
/>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
    />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"
            />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
<asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">
      <gdiScaling>true</gdiScaling>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

I do this to enable Windows 10's new GDI scaling. It works fine until I move my executable to a different location.

Surprisingly, copying the entire directory doesn't help, so the system doesn't need the manifest or the resource file. The path seems to be hardcoded somewhere.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my manifest was bad. It didn't include the xmlns:asmv3 parameter

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" manifestVersion="1.0">
```

Comment: That's not a parameter. It's a namespace declaration for a namespace you are using. Any capable XML editor would have made you aware of the issue.